# taking sum of rows in R based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data in this format

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 2 |
| B | 5 | 2 |
| C | 2 | 3 |
| C | 5 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 1 |
| B | 7 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 2 |

I want to get a new column with the sum of the rows of ColB, something like this:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 8 |
| B | 5 | 2 | 8 |
| C | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| C | 5 | 3 | 7 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| B | 7 | 2 | 8 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 8 |

Thanks much for your help!

I tried

```r
df$ColD <- with(df, sum(ColB[ColC == 1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want `ColD` to have the sum of `ColB` for each consecutive group defined by the values in `ColA`. In which case, we may do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(group = data.table::rleid(ColA)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(ColD = sum(ColB)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    ColA   ColB  ColC  ColD
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 A         2     1     3
#>  2 A         1     1     3
#>  3 B         3     2     8
#>  4 B         5     2     8
#>  5 C         2     3     7
#>  6 C         5     3     7
#>  7 A         1     1     4
#>  8 A         3     1     4
#>  9 B         7     2     8
#> 10 B         1     2     8
```

This, at any rate, is the same as the expected output.

<sup>Created on 2023-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"B", "B"), ColB = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L), 
    ColC = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
df$ColD=ave(
  df$ColB,
  cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(match(df$ColA,LETTERS))))),
  FUN=sum
)

   ColA ColB ColC ColD
1     A    2    1    3
2     A    1    1    3
3     B    3    2    8
4     B    5    2    8
5     C    2    3    7
6     C    5    3    7
7     A    1    1    4
8     A    3    1    4
9     B    7    2    8
10    B    1    2    8
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution:

```r
df |>
  transform(ColD = ave(ColB, with(rle(ColA), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = sum))

   ColA ColB ColC ColD
1     A    2    1    3
2     A    1    1    3
3     B    3    2    8
4     B    5    2    8
5     C    2    3    7
6     C    5    3    7
7     A    1    1    4
8     A    3    1    4
9     B    7    2    8
10    B    1    2    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another *base* solution using `ave`.

```
df$ColD <- ave(df$ColB, c(0, cumsum(diff(df$ColC) != 0)), FUN=sum) #Using ColC
#df$ColD <- ave(df$ColB, c(0, cumsum(df$ColA[-nrow(df)] != df$ColA[-1])), FUN=sum) #Using ColA

df
#   ColA ColB ColC ColD
#1     A    2    1    3
#2     A    1    1    3
#3     B    3    2    8
#4     B    5    2    8
#5     C    2    3    7
#6     C    5    3    7
#7     A    1    1    4
#8     A    3    1    4
#9     B    7    2    8
#10    B    1    2    8
```